# Apache2 ServerName and ServerAlias not working

Tags: apache, browser, server, virtualhost, server-name

On a nearly fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS computer, I would like to set up a virtual host on my local machine. So I created a `index.html` under `/var/www/test/` with the following content: 
`you have entered a test page`

I have set up a `test.conf` file under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@zhihu.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
    ServerName zhihu.com
    ServerAlias www.zhihu.com
    <Directory /var/www/test/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all granted     
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The localhost is working:[image: localhost is working]

`/etc/hosts` config is probably working as indicated by `ping`

```
ping zhihu.com
PING zhihu.com (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from xxx (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
```

but browser cannot bring me to the domain which should now be hosted in `/var/www/test/`.

[image]

I have also `a2ensite test.conf` and `a2dissite 000-default.conf` and `service apache2 reload`

So I think the only possible place for error to occur is `ServerName` and `ServerAlias`. Why are they not working?

Comment: @Pandurang inputting `https://zhihu.com` on browser redirects me to `https://www.zhihu.com` though. Did you mean something else?

Comment: HTTPS doesn't use port 80.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have not specified use of https anywhere but the browser brings me there even if I just input www.zhihu.com or zhihu.com. Anyway to change this behaviour? I used zhihu.com before so is there some cache that I need to clear?

Comment: My bad. Try with `http://zhhihu.com` in Incognito Browser.Also check if you are using any redirection in htaccess file or any other file.

Comment: `http://zhhihu.com` still directs me to `https://...` in a normal window so I use it in a private window. Now it shows me the `/var/www/html/index.php` default page instead of my page in `/var/www/test/`

Comment: @Pandurang there is no htaccess file or any other file in `/var/www/`

Comment: it is finally working. Thank you @Pandurang @ÁlvaroGonzález! Sorry I think I made mistake by not `a2ensite` every time I made an edit to test.conf. After I corrected that and used incognito mode every time, it is not necessary to replace `*` with `zhihu.com`. If you could turn it to an answer with incognito mode and `a2ensite` I will happily accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please enable VirtualHost using a2ensite and access site in incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the ssl certificate for the site includes both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
and ServerAlias is set to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Your `UseCanonicalName` setting may be `Off` by default.

> UseCanonicalName: Determines how Apache constructs self-referencing
> URLs and the SERVER_NAME and SERVER_PORT variables. When set “Off”,
> Apache will use the Hostname and Port supplied by the client. When set
> “On”, Apache will use the value of the ServerName directive.

If you are using a tunnel (ngrok), the hostname supplied by the client may differ.

I was able to override the setting in httpd-default.conf

`UseCanonicalName On`

After this `ServerName` set in the vhosts file works properly.